# show tree inside the grid columns in extjs 4

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I have to create a cube structure and for this I want to load a different tree panels under each of the  columns of extjs grid panel.Is it possible to have  the grid panel to show the tree panel under each of its columns.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in a grid? Wouldn't it be easier to just put your TreePanels in a container with column layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer TreeGrid component for this. I hope you are looking for this implementation. You can refer sencha kitchen sink link with example. Please refer below URL which may help you.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid

Thanks.

Comment: TreeGrid only supports a single tree column. I believe he is asking how to have a tree per column.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to use this TreeGrid for your project.
[TreeGrid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/treegrid.html)

Comment: TreeGrid only supports a single tree column. I believe he is asking how to have a tree per column.

Answer (score 0):

No. Grid panel does not support this.

What's more, it does not make much sense from a functionality point of view - trees have nodes that can be expanded and collapsed. The only way this can work with a grid is if there is only one tree column; only then you can collapse or expand specific rows. But how would this work if there are different trees in different columns.

I'd take on rixo's recommendation and use a column layout in which there are trees. Although I still can't really see how users would benefit from such a screen.